# Where is the VIP code I need to link my online account to my gamertag in Xbox 360?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

To link my online account to my gamertag in Xbox 360 I apparently need a VIP code.

Where do I find that in Black Ops?

Comment: Maybe buying the prestige version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the callofduty.com [profile avatar page](http://www.callofduty.com/profile/avatar) I managed to get to the [link account page](http://www.callofduty.com/CoDWW/profile/linking). From there is a link to an instructions page for "[I can't find my VIP Code!](http://www.callofduty.com/CoDWW/intel/172)"

Unfortunately these seem to apply to COD:World At War. I.e. "CoDWW" appears in the URL.

**Update:**

I think I've done it, rather than linking my account through the edit profile pages I did it via [the theater section](http://www.callofduty.com/theater/link). This did not require a VIP code. I just needed to login to my Playstation Network account. I imagine the process would be similar for Xbox 360.